# get text from textbox1 and set it on textblock1 in other form

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

i want to get input from textbox1 on form1 and set it on form2's textblock1
but the text wont showed

form1 code:

```
    private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(textbox1.Text + ".txt");
        var line = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
        if (textbox1.Text == line[0] && tb2.Password == line[1])
           {
               textbox1.Text = line[0];
               Frame.Navigate(typeof(form2));                    
           }
    }

    public string MyValue
    {
        get { return textbox1.Text; }
    }
```

code on form2

```
    var logged = new MainPage();
    textblock1.Text = logged.MyValue;
```

any help ?
thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try 
form1

```
 Frame.Navigate(typeof(form2), textbox1.Text);
```

form2

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string name = e.Parameter as string;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    {
          textblock1.Text = name ;
    }
    else
    {
        textblock1.Text = "Name is required.  Go back and enter a name.";
    }
}
```

this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx) maybe helps

Answer (score 1):

You don't get the desired value in `form2` because you're creating a new instance of `MainPage` which of course doesn't hold the values form the instance you have just navigated from.

You will need to pass the value as a parameter to `form2`. For that purpose you can use a different overload of `Navigate` which takes an additional parameter:

```
private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(textbox1.Text + ".txt");
    var line = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
    if (textbox1.Text == line[0] && tb2.Password == line[1])
    {
        textbox1.Text = line[0];
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(form2), textbox1.Text);                    
    }
}
```